# How to preserve original color coding of output on the shell while doing a subprocess.Popen?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a simple Python script which live-prints the output of a command. Following is the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess

def RunSubProcess(process, process_args):
    process = subprocess.Popen([process, process_args], 
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               stderr=subprocess.PIPE, 
                               universal_newlines=True)
    while process.stdout.readable():
        line = process.stdout.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line.strip())

RunSubProcess('ls', '-la')
```

The script works well for what it should do but it loses color coding of the output on my shell. If I type `ls -la`, I get the output well-colored. But if I run the above Python script, it gives the output **un**colored.

Is there an argument to `subprocess.Popen` that could preserve color coding of the shell it's running on?

**PS:**
I am running this Python script on a bash shell on MacOS with Python 3.9.0 installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many programs detect whether they are connecterd to a terminal, and switch to different behaviors for interactive use.

Some provide options to force interactive features (try `ls --color=always` but what exactly works depends on your platform; this is not standardized behavior. The [macOS `ls` man page](https://ss64.com/osx/ls.html) says to set  `CLICOLOR=yes` in the environment) and others can be fooled into believing they are running interactively by using the `pty` library, or `pexpect` which is a higher-level package and somewhat easier to work with.

Comment: You should generally [avoid `ls` in scripts](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but I'm guessing you are using it as an example.

Comment: Yes, `ls` is just an example to demonstrate my issue

Comment: Is it possible to color code the output of `stderr` only in red? It should be. I should try to do some tricks in that `print` call

Comment: You can easily add color codes to standard error on the Python side. You have to capture it from your `subprocess` invocation, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This works and maintains color for me.

```py
               cmd = "/bin/ls -l --color"

               # Run command. Print output in real-time. Maintain text colors.                                                                                
                proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)                                                                              
                for line in iter(proc.stdout.readline, ""):                                                                                                    
                    line = line.decode("utf-8")                                                                                                                
                    if line == "":                                                                                                                             
                        break                                                                                                                                  
                    print(line.rstrip())                                                                                                                       
                rc = proc.poll()                                                                                                                               
                while rc is None:                                                                                                                              
                    time.sleep(0.1)                                                                                                                            
                    rc = proc.poll()
```